# Accessing main class from Jersey listener without the main class being a singleton object

Tags: java, jersey

I often use Jersey simple server as a webservice in my Java applications. Whenever I do this I only seem to be able to fetch properties from my application (`main` class) if it is setup as a singleton. So, I only seem to be able to fetch the information with `MainClass.getInstance()`.

I know I can make the Jersey listener some sort of singleton in Jersey but this only means that the listener object will be instantiated once within Jersey in stead of for every single request: The listener is not a real singleton because it still needs a `public` constructor.

Is there a way to access my application class without it being a singleton object itself?

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class JerseyService {

    private MainClass mainClass;
    private int port = 8080;
    private DefaultResourceConfig config;
    private Closeable jerseyServer;

    public JerseyService() {
        config = new DefaultResourceConfig(JerseyListener.class); // Attach the listener (resource) to the Jersey server
        jerseyServer = SimpleServerFactory.create("http://0.0.0.0:" + jerseyPort, config);
    }

    public String getData() {
        return "somedata";
    }

}

@Path("/")
public class JerseyListener {

    @Path("getData")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getData() {
        // How can i call getData() from JerseyService
        // without JerseyService being a singleton??
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("{<jsondata>}").build();
    }

}
```

Comment: If your class is not supposed to be a singleton then what it can be?

Comment: A public accessible class. Normally I would pass the main class as an argument to the listener. But as I cannot instantiate the listener myself (because that is done by Jersey) I'm unable to do so.

Comment: What listener do you mean?

Comment: A custom class that acts as a Jersey Resource listener. The class that gets wrapped in the DefaultResourceConfig and attached to the simple server.

Comment: What kind of resources it listens? Also show the code attaching it to the simple server.

Comment: I will extend the question with the code...